# Where is the 'Leave a Copy of the messages on the server' option in Mail settings for 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Here's my issue. With my new Dell XPS Ultrabook I have installed Office and Outlook 2013. The problem is that I need to keep emails on the server so emails are ALSO downloaded to my other computers. However as was the case with 2010, under email settings - Advanced: Delivery. There isn't the option to click : Leave a copy of messages on the server.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

According to me, It's comes under 
 => Account setting 
    => More Settings 
       => E-mail Settings dialog box. 
          => The Advanced tab
                => Check "Leave a copy of each message on server" check box.
then 
            OK.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is under: File | Account Settings | [select the account from the list] | Change | More Settings | Advanced.

I am using a POP setup.  This might be different for IMAP or Exchange.